# argmax of homogeneous function

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, optimization

**EDITS APPEAR IN BOLD**

We want to compute 
$$
p^\star = \text{argmin}_{p\in \mathbb{R}^n} \quad 1/2f(p)^2- p\cdot g(p)
$$
where $f: \mathbb{R}^n\mapsto \mathbb{R}$  **is a (smooth) norm** and
$g: \mathbb{R}^n\mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$ is smooth.

So the objective function can be written in the form
$$
1/2f(p)^2- f(p) \left(\frac{p}{f(p)}\cdot g(p)\right)
$$

We introduce 
$$
\pi^\star = \text{argmax}_{\pi | f(\pi)=1} \quad  \pi\cdot g(\pi)
$$

Then 
$$
p^\star = \left(\pi^\star \cdot g(\pi^\star)\right) \pi^\star
$$

I don't understand the result, especially why is it natural to introduce $\pi^\star$ ?

We can easily get convinced in dim 1 = n.

Thanks for your enlightenment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $f(p) = p$ you obtain $\pi^*=1$ and $p^* = g(1)$. So, the claim is that:
$$\text{argmin}_{p} 1/2p^2 - p g(p) = g(1).$$
This is not necessarily true, for example when $g(p) = -(p-1)$:
$$\text{argmin}_{p} 1/2p^2 + p(p-1) = \frac{1}{3} \neq 0 = g(1).$$

Comment: no the objective function contains $p \cdot g(p)$ and it is homogeneous of degree 1 in $p$ so your function is not a valid candidate

Comment: @Smilia I changed the objective function in my answer. What exactly should be homogeneous of degree 1? I think $f$ is.

Comment: oh that's right thanks for this point, I edtited my post to consider the case where $f(p)$ is in fact a norm ... it should be more interesting

Comment: @Smilia that does not affect the answer much. Just take $f(p)=|p|$, then $\pi^* = -1$ (for my choice of $g$), but $g(-1) \neq 1/3$.